# SQLite VFS working with a stream

Tags: sqlite, stream, vfs

I need an SQLite implementation that allows me to have the db file encrypted on disk, for security reasons. I noticed that SQLite only works with regular files, and that there's no implementation that supports streams available (oddly enough, as many people seem to want one). If I had such an implementation, I could easily pass it a stream that encrypts/decrypts the file first.

After googling and reading about the matter, it seems like a custom VFS might solve the problem, implementing only the file methods to open, read, write etc. to a stream instead of a regular file (the other methods may keep the default behavior).

My question then is as follows: 
1. Does that sound like the correct approach? 
2. Is there really no such implementation available??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an encrypted sqlite database there is [The SQLite Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html). If not- ignore my answer.

Comment: I suppose that would work, however, isn't there anything that does it for free? My customized-VFS idea doesn't sound too hard to implement, I'm just surprised no one has already done it.

Comment: It should be feasable to replace the existing VFS however I never looked at it.